# Do we have an eyedropper?

Tags: graphics

Assume you are not in Manipulate or Animate or anything dynamic.  It would be really nice to be able to touch a color in an image and seed colors into ImageRecolor.  Have I overlooked a function?

Comment: There is an eyedropper at menu `Graphics | Drawing Tools | More colors`

Comment: That suggest I should be using DynamicModule and EventHandler. So, I'll try.

Comment: The eyedropper causes an FE crash (on `Graphics`) for me. V12.2, Mac (Big Sur 11.2.3). Reported to WRI [CASE:4798370].

Comment: The eyedropper crash is a known issue and WRI is working on a fix for a future release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context menu of an image displayed in the front end, there is "Get Pixel Color". A tool and tooltip pop up. Click the image, instructions for copying the color "coordinates" appear in the tooltip ("Cmd-c" on a Mac). Then perform the copy command and you can paste the coordinates.  The coordinates appear to be the color coordinates in the color space defined by the image.